# Function return different response using $q.defer in controller and resolve

Tags: angularjs, json, angular-ui-router, angular-controller

I have created a state using state provider and i used `resolve`, i called api using factory.

```
.state('Test', {
    url: '/Test/:testId',       
    templateUrl: TEMPLATE_URL + 'Test/test.html',
    controller: "testController",
    resolve: { 
         getTest : function($stateParams,TestFactory){
                 return testFactory.getTest($stateParams.testId);
         },   
          testId: ['$stateParams', function ($stateParams) {
          return $stateParams.testId;
        }]
    }
  });
})
```

I have created a factory having a function(getTest ) which return the object

```
getTest : function(parmTestId){
             var deferred = $q.defer();
             $http.get(API_URL + "Test/testById?testId="+parmTestId).success(deferred.resolve)
              .error(deferred.resolve);
              return deferred.promise;           
         }
```

I have created controller, inject provider

```
.controller("testController", function($scope,$rootScope,$http,getTest,testId, TestFactory ){
     console.log(getTest); // its work perfectly and return json object  
     var returnObj = TestFactory.getTest(testId); //I called factory function 
     console.log(returnObj)//its not return object its return Promiss
}
```

I am not able to understans when i call by state resolve, its return json object which is return from api call but when i call in the controller its not retrun json object. 
Its return

```
Promise {$$state: Object}
$$state: Object
status: 1
value: Object
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Promise
```

In the value have the actual result which i want(json object)
Question is in both case, why its return different object ?

Thank you in advance. if you dont understand this i will discuss in comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's returning a promise object, which is waiting to be handled!

You may use `.then(successCallback, errorCallback)` for the same:

```
var returnObj = TestFactory.getTest(testId).then(
  function(res) {
    // The 1st argument passed in this function is the response object
    console.log(res);
  },
  function(err) {
    // This is called in case the request fails
    console.log('Some error: ', err);
  }
);
```

Also, found the bug in your `getTest` method:

```
$http.get(API_URL + "Test/testById?
    testId="+parmTestId).success(function(res) { deferred.resolve(res); })
                  .error(function(err) { deferred.reject(err); });
                  return deferred.promise;
```

deferred.resolve and deferred.reject are methods, so you have to call them!

Comment: Thank You its working fine. But i dont understand why in resolve its return actual object without handling it ?

Comment: Your Testfactory's `getTest` method might be returning something like this: `return $http.get(url)`. You haven't posted it's code but I am pretty sure about that!

Comment: in my api call there is no any issue its working fine. and run code without error. but question is still in my mind

Comment: The issue is not with your api. And even though you are making the request in the correct manner, but you are not handling it correctly. `$http.get` , `$http.post` etc return Promises in angular, which have to be resolved to access the response.

Comment: ok i will do according to your response. but in state resolve i have not handle promiss response but its return json object without write `.then(funcion(res){})`

Comment: You are calling `planFactory.getTest`, not `TestFactory.getTest`. That method might have been already returning the response in the required format!

Comment: sorry by mistake i have not to change that code that is not planFactory its testFactory. I can't share actual code here so i changed it in dummy code

Comment: Are you sure that is works in the resolve? According to the code you posted above, it should not.

Comment: yes. its working fine and its return result (json Object)

Comment: I got my question's answer. Thank you @avijit gupta to solve my problem and solve my curiosity.

Comment: Cannot comment on that until I see your actual code!

Comment: this is link you can also refer it for more about and it will help you ahead https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve . and also you like my post

Answer (score 0):

when you are use

```
.then(function(res){
    ..
    },function(err){
    ....
});
```

its return res object which have status,data,.... etc so you can take it from res.data

when you use

```
.success(function(res){
     .......
   });
```

its retrun actual data data.